# Calling an array inside awk to create a table with fixed-width columns

Tags: awk, columns

I would like to extract data from a file and organize it in a big fixed-widths table. I can expect that this table will have multiple columns, let's say 30 columns. If I create this table using the traditional `awk` command line, then I will need to write a very long `awk` command line, something similar to the following:

```
awk '{printf "%-5s  %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30}'
```

Is there anyway to make this linear shorter? For example, I am thinking of implementing an array inside the previous long command. This array will tell `awk` what are the numbers and the widths of the columns that I would like to create, instead of defining each column separately, something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for i in {1..30}; do echo %-5s\n print i}
```

How can I implement that correctly inside `awk` to create multiple fixed-widths columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the print, itself, inside a loop, one field at a time.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%-5s",$i } ; printf("\n"); }'
```

Note the printing of the newline is needed after the loop to prevent multiple lines all merging into one.

e.g

```
echo a b c 32 87 x5 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%-5s",$i } ; printf("\n"); }'
a    b    c    32   87   x5
```

Comment: Before the `for` loop you could do something like `sum += $27` and then at the very end you can use something like `END { print sum}` to print it out

Answer (score 1):

You could (but I do not recommend this) build some vars in steps (an example in bash):

```
$ printf -v l '%s ' {1..30}           # list of numbers to use
$ printf -v a '%.0s%%-5s ' $l         # make a string of repeated "%-5s"
$ printf -v b ',$%s' $l               # make string of field numbers as "$1,$2.."
$ awk -va="$a" '{printf a "\n"'"$b"'}' infile4
```

But you could also do it all inside awk:

```
$ awk '{split($0,a); for(i in a){printf "%-5s", $i}; print ""}' infile
```

- The `split` in `awk` will use the same regex in `FS` as used to split the line into fields and place each value in the array `a`.
- The `for` will (auto) loop over all fields.
- The `printf` will print all fields with the same format.
- And, the final `print` will place a newline at the end of the line.

This is more flexible as it will work for any amount of fields, even lines with varying number of fields. And is complete inside only one language (easier to understand and maintain).

Or even:

```
$ awk 'for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ printf("%-5s",$i) }; print ""}' infile
```

You may change the format to `%-5.5s` to cut fields that are longer than 5 characters.

Note that awk's printf incorrectly counts decomposed character like `é` as two characters. It seems to count Unicode code points (a common issue) instead of Unicode clusters.

---

**EDIT**
Answering this additional question from the comments:

> sum the rows that define column #27 in my table

Just add the needed code:

```
$ awk '{split($0,a); 
        sum=sum+a[27];
        for(i in a){ printf "%-5s", $i };
        print ""
       } END {
       print "Sum of column 27 is =", sum }
      ' infile
```

Comment: Hey, ... You could still select this answer as the accepted one ! :-)